# Как удалить скачанное изображение из временной папки на сервере после генерации из неё миниатюры?

Tags: php, wordpress, download, thumbnails

Есть сайт на *wordpress* и я планирую создавать посты с миниатюрами получаемыми с внешнего `url` посредством загрузки через API.
Непосредственно сам процесс создания постов я настроил:

```
$post_data = array(
  'post_title'    => sanitize_text_field( $name ),
  'post_content'  => $content,
  'post_category' => array(1),
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_type'      => 'post',
  'post_author' => 1
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
```

а изображения получаю с помощью функции
`$image_id = wp_insert_attachment_by_url( $url, $post_id );` которая описана в [гисте по ссылке](https://gist.github.com/lenivene/22691fee7b8e95619055e59793228b09) Но, при этом, при генерации миниатюры в папке остаётся копия скачанного изображения, которое теперь занимает лишнее место на диске.

И теперь у меня остался вопрос: как удалять исходники изображений полученных во временной папке при помощи `download_url`, но при этом, чтобы сама сохранялась **миниатюра (thumbnail)**?

```
function wp_insert_attachment_by_url( $url, $post_ID ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    if ( '' == $post_ID )
        return new WP_Error( 'insert_attachment_failed', __( 'Invalid post ID' ) );

    if( !empty( $url ) ){
        $url = esc_url( $url );

        /**
         * Set variables for storage, fix file
         * filename for query strings.
         */
        preg_match( '/[^\?]+\.(jpe?g|jpe|gif|png)\b/i', $url, $matches );
        if ( ! $matches ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'insert_attachment_failed', __( 'Invalid image URL' ) );
        }

        $file_array = array();
        $file_array['name'] = basename( $matches[0] );

        /**
        * Download file to temp location.
        */
        $file_array['tmp_name'] = download_url( $url );

        /**
        * Check for download errors
        * if there are error unlink the temp file name
        */
        if ( is_wp_error( $file_array['tmp_name'] ) ) {
            return $file_array['tmp_name'];
        }

        $image_ID = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_ID );

        /**
         * If error storing permanently, unlink.
         */
        if ( is_wp_error( $image_ID ) ) {
            @unlink( $file_array['tmp_name'] );
            return $image_ID;
        }

        /**
         * If error thumbnail
         */
        if ( false === set_post_thumbnail( $post_ID, $image_ID ) ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'insert_attachment_failed', __( 'Problem to set post thumbnail' ) );
        }

        return $image_ID;
    }else{
        return new WP_Error( 'insert_attachment_failed', __( 'Insert URL' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверняка остаётся не копия, а оригинал. Даже если он не используется - он нужен. Не хочешь "копий" - загружай в медиатеку сразу нужного размера и выводи оригинал, а не тумбу.

Comment: @SeVlad как предлагаете загрузить в медиатеку нужного размера оригинал?
"Даже если он не используется - он нужен." И можете пояснить для каких целей нужен?
Главная причина почему я задался такой целью: это объем необходимого пространства для этих целей, т.к. часть из изображений неоптимизированные и некоторые "весят" и 7мб и даже 13мб, а если элементов 10тыс+ и тем более 100тыс+, то сами понимаете какой доступный объем диска должен быть на сервере

Comment: Слишком много вопросов. Тем более для комментов. скажу по основному - подготавливать изображения в твоём случае  (приводить размеры, оптимизировать и тд) нужно ДО того, как их регистрировать их в медиатеке. Для этого у php есть все средства. Логика работы проста - получаешь, приводишь в порядок, заливаешь в медиатеку. Или после приведения в порядок заливаешь в нужное место,  проверяешь наличие, регистрируешь в медиатеке.

Comment: @SeVlad спасибо за ваш совет!
Я протестировал много вариантов решений и в итоге нашёл только одно рабочее, которое адаптировал к своей задаче, но в нём все манипуляции проводятся ПОСЛЕ регистрации в медиатеке и оно работает. Решение приложил ниже. ДО регистрации у меня не получилось сделать так, чтобы заработало. 
Если вы поделитесь своим вариантов решения, то буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было найдено на просторах интернета, которое я адаптировал под конкретно свою задачу.

По итогу, как мне и было необходимо, в папке остаётся только одно изображение в заданных размерах `thumbnail` (название сохраняет оригинальное без хвостовой части с размерами) и оно же прикрепляется в качестве миниатюры к посту.

Протестировано на актуально на сегодня версии **Wordpress 6.1.1**

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 250, 250 );
function true_remove_default_sizes( $sizes ) {
    unset( $sizes[ 'medium' ] );
    unset( $sizes[ 'large' ] );
    unset( $sizes[ 'medium_large' ] );
    unset( $sizes[ '1536x1536' ] );
    unset( $sizes[ '2048x2048' ] );
    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );

function replace_uploaded_image($image_data) {

  if (!isset($image_data['sizes']['thumbnail'])) return $image_data;

  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $uploaded_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' .$image_data['file'];
  $current_subdir = substr($image_data['file'],0,strrpos($image_data['file'],"/"));
  $thumbnail_image_location = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/'.$current_subdir.'/'.$image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']['file'];

  unlink($uploaded_image_location);

  rename($thumbnail_image_location,$uploaded_image_location);

  $image_data['width'] = $image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']['width'];
  $image_data['height'] = $image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']['height'];
  unset($image_data['sizes']['thumbnail']);

  return $image_data;
}

add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','replace_uploaded_image');
```

Comment: 1. "без хвостовой части с размерами" это не миниатюра, а оригинал. Не thumbnail, а full. 2. Ты сделал тоже о чем говорил я, только переложил на ВП функции обработки графики (при этом каким-то корявым способом), вместо того чтобы сделать это на чистом php . Это не очень хорошо, тк создаёт ненужную нагрузку.

Comment: @SeVlad
1. К посту прикрепляется именно thumbnail, а не full с размерами миниатюры, я все  верно написал (от оригинала весом в 1мб в папке uploads остается только миниатюра весом 20кб и размером thumbnail width/height)
2. функции-обертки вп специально и созданы для работы в вп, т.к. дополнительно проходят все необходимые проверки, очистки и фильтры скрытые под капотом движка

Comment: 1. На бис: все миниатюры имеют формат имени файла `filename-WxH`, где `W` и `H` - это размеры в пикселях. Без размеров - это full. Учи матчасть. 2. Функции ВП не имеют отношения к предварительной подготовке графики  Но хочешь нагружать движок ненужными действия - дело твоё, никто тебе этого запретить не может.

Comment: @SeVlad не понимаю в чём вы хотите меня исправить - может быть вы неверно меня поняли? Я написал, что моя функция делает такие преобразования, что `thumbnail` условно теперь становится original и маскируется под `full`, т.е. теперь при вызове, что `get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' )` что `get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail' )` вызовется один и то же файл `filename` без хвостовой части с размерами, т.к. только он один и остаётся в папке.